# Creating an autoupdate for my program and its database

Tags: database, sql, windows

I've already an offline updater as a download but I want to make it automatically. It's a client/server software and a ms sql database.

3 parts have to be updated:

1. update of a proprietary software (setup.exe with next, next, type login/password for server service, finish) which delivers a WinClient and a Service for the server. Autoupdate is only needed for server, the autoupdate for clients by the server works already.
2. one .hug file which contains new customized program version. The path is a directory in the above software and can be determined with registry.
3. MS SQL database update with new content (in a .bak file) and structural changes. The database server is sometimes another server as application server. At the moment you have to type in the SQL instance when running the udpater.

My ideas are these:

- a updater program in the tray on application server and database server
  updater searches with a timer for newer versions on my ftp server and downloads the files if existing
- on application server it runs the setup.exe and copies the .hug file. Maybe I could make it silent with command prompt commands. But still need to fill in login/password for the service user.
- on database server I configure the autoupdater once with instance name. Updater downloads .bak-file and runs sql script with insert, update and alter statements.
- but one big problem which can cause problems is when users are still logged in. Don't know in the moment how I could solve that.

So what is a good way to realise such a project. Or is there already some auto-update software availabe which I could use or customize?

Comment: [Green fields, blue skies, and the white board - what is too broad?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6961/31260)

Comment: You should use signed updates. Or if you can't program them, at least use HTTPS. Preferably use both.